Identifying stochastic process from data
Suppose I am given the values of a stochastic process $S_t$ satisfying some unknown SDE from say 2000 to 2024 so I have a lot a data. How do I identify, model this stochastic process ?
First I thought of making a histogram of its values and try to guess what distribution it comes from but histograms are made to guess the distribution of i.i.d. samples meanwhile here each $S_t$ follows is probably $f(W_t$) where $W_t$ is a brownian motion so a histogram isn't useful.
Is there any way do it because I never heard of such type of modeling. Also, I intuitively don't think there are ways since two geometric brownian motions with same parameters can be so different for example, so how to make a good guess ?

A model that cannot be rejected for the given observations does not need to be described by an SDE. It may suffice to stay within the "discrete time" time series analysis.

See if your time series is bounded.  If it is one-side bounded, it may makes sense to model the logarithm.

Assuming homoschedasticity (no "local vol" in the SDE terms), try using some Auto-ARIMA tool to estimate such ARIMA.  This will firstly pick up integration, e.g. stock value vs its return (if you have not done this yet by switching to logs) and then show if the process is at least stationary.  If such ARIMA is estimated, then you are done.  All you need is to extract the residuals and, if really necessary, estimate a parametric model for them, which may turn out to be Gaussian indeed.

If 2 does not work, then you will first have to identify the source of non-stationarity beyond integration (trends, seasonality), correct for those and goto 2.

In rare occasions when homoscedasticity is rejected, you may have to resort to ARMA-GARCH


This stuff is more practical and far less restrictive than trying to identify an SDE.
Good luck

To see if it's lognormal, check if the log follows a normal distribution (statistical test, there are many). To see if it is normal, check if itself follows a normal distribution. Maybe you want a mixture and calibrate the parameters using max likelihood. It ALL depends on your end goal - what do you want to do?

But if the log of $S_t$ follows say $c*N(0,t)$ how will I know it with only 1 observation ?

My goal once I know what process is $S_t$ is to do some asset pricing, I'll take $E(f(S_t))$

$log(S_t/S_(t-1)$ is normal and you have about 24 years of observations

I agree. However, in what "units" is $t$ ? For example if my first observation is Jan 1st 2000 at 00:00 and I have observations each 5 minutes so the second observation is at Jan 1st 2000 00:05, then is $S_2$ so distributed as $N(0,2)$ or as $N(0,5)$, idk if my question is clear

Its in years right ?
